# What is the difference between Images and RawImages in Unity?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

I was pondering about what the difference is between an Image and a RawImage in Unity. I was trying to learn Unity's fundamentals since I'm learning to script when I encountered RawImages, so I'm asking what's the point of RawImages if we already have Images. If there even is a point to RawImages, how can I use them?

I attempted reading many forum posts and articles from the Unity website and other third-party websites, but the vocabulary was a bit too complex, so I'll need to have it explained to me in simple terms. Even ChatGPT couldn't really help me! I want to know the difference so I can improve the quality of my scripts and overall become better with UI.

Comment: `The Raw Image can display any Texture whereas an Image component can only show a Sprite Texture. Note : Keep in mind that using a RawImage creates an extra draw call with each RawImage present, so it's best to use it only for backgrounds or temporary visible graphics.` from docs.

Comment: Its used when you have texture data but do not want to convert to sprite, because that operation is costly.  Showing a "live feed" from a different camera is a common use.

Comment: Can you explain that in simple terms? I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: `The Raw Image can display any Texture whereas an Image component can only show a Sprite Texture.`  This is as simple as it gets.

Comment: You can check here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1070280/raw-image-vs-image.html